# Narrow down the search result when I start typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for Idea here.. I will try coding with your idea and let you know if I ve any issues..

### Issue

I ve one text box and list of names in the page. When I start typing , I want search result should narrow down. Eg. When I type 'a' in the text box, the results should narrow down and it should contain only name s with 'a.

Please let me know if any methods available in jquery ???

Answer (score 4):

Try [jQuery UI's Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: Hi Amadan,, I m not looking for auto-complete. I ve tried auto-complte and it worked for filling things to the text field... I want change in the search result. Thx for your reply and let me know any other methods or approach you are aware of.. Thanks again !!

Comment: Oh. Your question was confusing. If you are trying to filter out search results as you type, you need AJAX, and reissue the search request as you type. If you want to filter out things that already exist on the page, you need to iterate over them and either remove or hide those that don't match.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
    $('#search').on('keyup', function () {
       var str = $('#result ul li:contains(' + $(this).val().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ')');
       if (str) {
          $('#result ul li').hide();
          str.show();
       } else {
          $('#result ul li').show();
       }
    });
```

Comment: I did it - `$(document).ready(function()
{
 jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
     return function( elem ) {
         return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
     };
 });
 $("#txt_SearchCategoryName").keyup(function(event)
 {
  if($.trim($("#txt_SearchCategoryName").val()) != "")
  {
   $("#table_viewContent #tr_dealerName").hide();
   $("#table_viewContent #tr_dealerName :Contains("+$("#txt_SearchCategoryName").val()+")").closest("tr").show();
  }
  else
  {
   $("#table_viewContent #tr_dealerName").show();
  }
 }
 );
});`